# MVC Why is this dropdown mandatory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this dropdown in my view (actually I have many of these in a loop)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAttributeValueIds[i], Model.AttributeValuesList[Convert.ToInt32(type.Value)], "Select a value")
```

The relevant parts of the model are

```
public IDictionary<int, List<SelectListItem>> AttributeValuesList { get; set; }
public List<int> SelectedAttributeValueIds { get; set; }
```

The dropdowns above contains the correct list of values.  If I select one of the values and submit then the value selected is correctly posted and correctly saved into the SelectedAttributeValueIds list.

Now the problem is that if I do not select a value from one or more of these dropdowns my ModelState.IsValid is false in my post action method.  Looking at the error list, the reason is that

> "a value is required"

Why are the dropdowns mandatory?  I'd like them to be optional.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is because you use `[Required]` attribute in Model, if not you can change the property type to nullable one :

```
public List<int?> SelectedAttributeValueIds { get; set; }
```

Comment: I didn't have a required attribute on it but I will try the nullable idea. - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `SelectedAttributeValueIds` property is a list of ints that have an implicit value. If you want it to have no value, change the type to a nullable int using `List<int?>`.

If you really want to leave it as `int` you can set `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` to `false` in your `Global.asax` I'd recommend using the int? however.